# Android actionbar and metro design

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar

I have been struggling with all of this backwards compatibility and support libraries and would really appreciate some help.

I would like to implement a project which has an action bar on top for navigation and settings and stuff like that, and I want to use metro design themes. I do not care about backwards compatibility.

My question is how do I do this ? What are the classes and themes that I need ?

This is my code so far. In the "LogIn" activity I see the ActionBar but in the "registration" activity I don't.

LogIn.xml:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        tools:context=".LogIn.LoginActivity">

        <!-- Login progress -->
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/login_progress"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/login_form"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/login_BTN_new_registration"
                android:text="New Registration"
                style="@style/BoldCenterText"
                android:layout_above="@+id/email_login_form"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/email"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/prompt_username"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:singleLine="true" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/password"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                        android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                     android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                        android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:singleLine="true" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_above="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

                <TextView
                    android:text="Auto login"
                    style="@style/CenterText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    />

                <Switch
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"/>


            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
                style="@style/BoldCenterText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Log In"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Registration.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".LogIn.RegistrationActivity">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/registration_PB_progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/registration_LL_registration_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            style="@style/BoldCenterText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Create new account" />


        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                style="@style/BoldCenterText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Required" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/registration_ACTV_username"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_username"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/registration_ET_password1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/registration_ET_password2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_password_repeat"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <TextView
                style="@style/BoldCenterText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Optional" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/registration_ET_email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:text="Background color"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:paddingLeft="13sp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                <Spinner
                    android:padding="0sp"
                    android:id="@+id/registration_S_color"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/registration_BTN_register"
            style="@style/BoldCenterText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:padding="0sp"
            android:text="Register" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".LogIn.SplashScreen2"
        android:noHistory="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LogIn.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:noHistory="true" />
    <activity android:name=".Main.MainActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LogIn.RegistrationActivity"
        android:label="Registration"
        android:noHistory="true" />
</application>
```

AppTheme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Why don't I see the ActionBar in the registration activity?

Thank you

Comment: Check if you are extending activities with AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extends your activity with AppCompat activity then you can get the desired result

```
public class RegistrationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {}
```

For your information if you want to change the action bar title and subtitle:

```
if(getSupportActionBar()!=null{
getSupportActionBar.setTitle("Register");
getSupportActionBar.setSubTitle("SUb Title");
}
```

The above methods only  work if you have extended you activity with AppCompatActivity

Comment below if you need further help

Comment: Hey, one last question. AppCompatActiviy adds a v7.widget right ? So what is the difference between android.support.v7.widget and the android.widget ? and why would I want to use v7.widget for Toolbar rather than android.widget ?

Comment: Can you ask it as another question as it is not related to this question, because future user may get confused while referring this question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34239162/difference-between-support-v7-widgets-and-android-widgets-toolbar

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I forgot to extend AppCompatActivity in my RegistrationActivity.java

Sorry for wasting your time :)